# How can I build a Markov Model for text?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, text, markov-models

I am just getting to learn the implementation of Markov's model, and I am trying to build a code that automatically predicts the word that precedes a particular word. I want to use this to generate a 100-word composition using this random words(I hope you understand what I mean).

However, my code only returns a 100-word composition made up of only one word!

I am confused, I think I missed something crucial, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what that is.
I need some help.

Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
from urllib.request import urlopen

#calculating the total sun of words dictionary

def summ(wordlist):
    sump=0
    for word, value in wordlist.items():
        sump+=value
    return sump

def random_index(wordlist):
    randomindex=randint(1, summ(wordlist))
     for word,value in wordlist.items():
        randomindex-=value
        if randomindex<=0:
            return word
    
def clean_text(text):
    text=text.replace('\n',' ')
    text=text.replace('"','')

    symbols=['.',',',';',':']
        for symbol in symbols:
        text=text.replace(symbol,' {} '.format(symbol))
    words=text.split(' ')
    words=[word for word in words if len(word) != 0]

    #creating dictinary and dictionary and defining the appropriate terms
    wordict={}

    for i in range(1, len(words)):
        if words[i-1] not in wordict:
            wordict[words[i-1]]={}
        if words[i] not in wordict[words[i-1]]:
            wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]=0
        wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]+=1
    return wordict

text=str(urlopen('http://pythonscraping.com/files/inaugurationSpeech.txt').read(), 'UTF-8')

wordict=clean_text(text)

    length=100
chain=['I']

for i in range(0, length):
    newWord= random_index(wordict[chain[-1]])
    chain.append(newWord)
print(' '.join(chain))
```

Please feel free to ask me any question about the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody else answered the question, after battle and debugging the code for some time I finally found the bug.

You see, the code was meant to generate random words from the text obtained from [here](http://pythonscraping.com/files/inaugurationSpeech.txt), and then use those random words to create random 100-word composition.
as observed in this block of code:

def clean_text(text):
text=text.replace('\n',' ')
text=text.replace('"','')

```
symbols=['.',',',';',':']
    for symbol in symbols:
    text=text.replace(symbol,' {} '.format(symbol))
words=text.split(' ')
words=[word for word in words if len(word) != 0]

#creating dictinary and dictionary and defining the appropriate terms
wordict={}

for i in range(1, len(words)):
    if words[i-1] not in wordict:
        wordict[words[i-1]]={}
    if words[i] not in wordict[words[i-1]]:
        wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]=0
    wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]+=1
return wordict
```

the script works using a dictionary of dictionary. Each word in the text is added to the dictionary `worddict`, and in the lines:

```
if words[i-1] not in wordict:
        wordict[words[i-1]]={}
    if words[i] not in wordict[words[i-1]]:
        wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]=0
    wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]+=1
return wordict
```

words proceeding each the word in the dictionary `wordict` are added to the corresponding word in a dictionary. Therefore a dictionary of dictionary is formed.

The reason for my bug is that I used `int(1)` instead of letter(i), in the code. I used lines:

```
if words[i-1] not in wordict:
        wordict[words[i-1]]={}
    if words[i] not in wordict[words[i-1]]:
        wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]=0
    wordict[words[i-1]][words[1]]+=1
return wordict
```

instead of using lines:

```
if words[i-1] not in wordict:
        wordict[words[i-1]]={}
    if words[i] not in wordict[words[i-1]]:
        wordict[words[i-1]][words[i]]=0
    wordict[words[i-1]][words[i]]+=1
return wordict
```

to create the dictionary of dictionaries (note the difference between 1 and i).

you can write a comment if you need more explanation.